# AssyncTask.get() блокирует код и до него

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Про метод get() класса AsyncTask сказано, что при вызове его в основном потоке до завершения операции в AsyncTask, он будет ждать ее завершения полностью заблокировав вызвавший его поток. Разве это распространяется на код "до" вызова get()? Например при вызове get() в слушателе нажатий поток останавливается еще до вызова get() и операция указанная до get() тоже ждет конца операции в AsyncTask.
Но я вижу примеры в которых код до get() выполняется прежде чем поток будет заблокирован. Это устаревшие примеры?

```
    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        tvInfo.setText("Pre Execute");
    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 100500;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer i){
        super.onPostExecute(i);
        tvInfo.setText("Post Execute with result="+i);

    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(maTask == null) {return;}
    tvInfo.setText("GET IS PRESSED");
    try{
        Toast.makeText(this,"RESULT IS "+ maTask.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }catch(ExecutionException| InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (TimeoutException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"TIMEOUT EXCEPTION",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что у вас визуально `tvInfo.setText("GET IS PRESSED");` отрабатывает "после" завершения задачи?

Comment: @Keker, `setText` выполняется - не выполняется обновление экрана пока главный поток занят.

Comment: То есть setText() присваивает новое значение для  View, но не успевает обновится т.к. моментально вызывается get() который блокирует поток? Где можно подробнее прочитать про это, я думал что setText() и обновление на экране выполняются нераздельно